# What is the "secular concept of evil"?

Tags: good-and-evil, evil

> This chapter asks whether the concept of evil is exclusively religious
> or supernaturally loaded, and what it means to say that evil exists.
> Some atheists refuse to use the word “evil” because of what they see
> as its religious connotations. Yet many other atheists use “evil” in
> condemning atrocities such as the Holocaust, and serial killers such
> as Ted Bundy. The concept of evil, like that of forgiveness, is
> available for use by theists and atheists alike, in contrast to an
> exclusively religious concept such as that of sin. Evil exists in the
> way that courage, malice, or honesty exist; not as a mysterious
> supernatural force that is capable of taking over a person, but as a
> character trait and as a moral property of actions. The chapter
> concludes with an explication of the philosophical method of
> conceptual analysis, which will be applied to the concept of evil.

I have not read [this](https://academic.oup.com/book/6628/chapter-abstract/150635454?redirectedFrom=fulltext) book! I am specifically interested in whether "evil" is, in a secular world, intrinsically motivating - taken as - for evil people, or we can be evil motivated by e.g. money or fame. Likewise, if we can be evil but not perform evil actions, and vice versa.

FWIW, I would be happier without 'evil' and just thinking someone irrational, confused, etc.. Not out of forgiveness for anyone, but a wish for the death of God to be meaningful.

Comment: How is the concept of wishing harm to others as a basic motivation being evil difficult to understand?   Of course evil is a secular term.

Comment: As with many such issues, it will depend on the fundamental moral theory you select. There are several even within what is usually called secular, so you need to pick one.

Comment: I very much dislike the idea that if my evil acts are out of e.g. greed then they are in some sense excusable @Dcleve reminds me of confession